# Ask user to point to location on Android map

Tags: android, google-maps, gis

Imagine an Android app allowing user to enter details about a some physical location e.g. mountain: `title`, `description` and `latitude` with `longitude`.

What's the easy and nice way to help user point to a `(latitude, longitude)` on e.g. Android Google Maps? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let him select the location for himself. Create a listener on the map which, on click, will create a marker that's also draggable. Once done he would press some button which saves the markers position.

Something like this:

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
private Marker mLastMarker;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    // Once you entered the mode where the user creates a location, register a listener
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
            mLastMarker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().draggable(true).position(latLng));
        }
    });

    // Button that saves the location user chose
    Button saveButton;
    saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("TAG", "User chose: " + mLastMarker.getPosition().toString());
            // Once the creation mode has ended remove the listener
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(null);
        }
    });
    ...
}
```